# Replacement in a String with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace a string in C# with the class Regex but I don't know use the class properly.
I want replace the next appearance chain in the String "a"

```
":(one space)(one or more characters)(one space)"
```

by the next regular expression

```
":(two spaces)(one or more characters)(three spaces)"
```

Will anyone help me and give me the code and explains me the regular expresion used?

Comment: Well have you tried *anything* yet? What were the results? Do you have test input and expected output?

Comment: I have used the method Replace in the class String but this method doesn't serve for Regular Expressions. I try something like that String.Replace(": {1}.*. {1}",": {2}.*. {3}")) but this doesn't work

Comment: And what about `String.Replace(": .*. ",":  .*.   "))` ?

Comment: @JoseM.: Well have you looked at the `Regex` class? If you want to use regular expressions, that's the one to use...

Comment: I have explained the problem bad. I'm interesting in replace the appearances ina large String not only this specific String.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **string.Replace(string, string)**

try this one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

try this one

```
    private String StrReplace(String Str)
    {
        String Output = string.Empty;

        String re1 = "(:)( )((?:[a-z][a-z]+))( )";

        Regex r = new Regex(re1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(Str);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            String c1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String ws1 = m.Groups[2].ToString() + " ";
            String word1 = m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String ws2 = m.Groups[4].ToString() + "  ";

            Output = c1.ToString() + ws1.ToString() + word1.ToString() + ws2.ToString() + "\n";
            Output = Regex.Replace(Str, re1, Output);
        }

        return Output;
    }
```

Comment: I try this method but this method don't work with a regular expresion.I think I need a regular expresion for replace the string.

Comment: the code doesn't work, the output string is the same that the input.

Comment: as you can see semicolon ":" is added on your regular expression when you input the string like this **"abcd : abcd abcd"** the output will be **"abcd :  abcd   abcd"**

Answer (score 0):

Using [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

```
   var str = "Test string with : .*.  to replace";
   var newstr = str.Replace(": .*. ", ":  .*.   ");
```

Using [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var newstr = Regex.Replace(str,": .*. ", ":  .*.   ");
```

Comment: What's the point of using Regex.replace to do a replace that doesn't use regex? Also you might want to use [this Regex.replace link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx), and I'm fairly sure `.` and `*` are special characters in a regex.

Comment: I have explained the problema bad, i wanted to say how to replace any appearance that matches the regular expression with another regular expresion

Comment: The second option dones't works. Only replace the first appearance of the first match and the other appearances don't are replaced.

Comment: @JoseM.: Yes, you have changed the requirement after I answered!! However, `String.Replace` should handle this situation. You can use that